# Excel macro: how to ignore header row when checking columns

Tags: excel, vba

This `HideEmptyColumns()` macro hides all columns that don't have any data.  How do I modify it so that it ignores the header row (row 1)?

```
Sub HideEmptyColumns()
  Dim Col As Range
  For Each Col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns
     Col.EntireColumn.Hidden = RangeIsEmpty(Col)
  Next Col
End Sub

Function RangeIsEmpty(R As Range) As Boolean
  Dim Cell As Range
  RangeIsEmpty = True
  For Each Cell In R.Cells
     If Cell.Value <> "" Then
        RangeIsEmpty = False
        Exit For
     End If
  Next Cell
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check to see what row its on

```
Sub HideEmptyColumns()
  Dim Col As Range
  For Each Col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns
     Col.EntireColumn.Hidden = RangeIsEmpty(Col)
  Next Col
End Sub

Function RangeIsEmpty(R As Range) As Boolean
  Dim Cell As Range
  RangeIsEmpty = True
  For Each Cell In R.Cells
     'are we not on the first row (header row)
     If Cell.Row <> 1 Then
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
           RangeIsEmpty = False
           Exit For
        End If
     End If
  Next Cell
End Function
```